# SonarLint KeyNotFoundException

Tags: c#, sonarqube, sonarlint, sonarlint-vs

I'm seeing a strange error when using Sonar to analyse a C-sharp code base.

> 14:59:19.350 INFO  - SonarLint for Visual Studio version 1.3.0.0
>       14:59:20.154 ERROR - 
>       14:59:20.337 ERROR - Unhandled Exception: System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not
>   present in the dictionary.
>       14:59:20.338 ERROR -    at System.Collections.Immutable.ImmutableDictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key)
>       14:59:20.340 ERROR -    at SonarLint.Runner.Configuration.AddAnalyzerCommentRegularExpression(Builder
>   builder)
>       14:59:20.341 ERROR -    at SonarLint.Runner.Configuration.Analyzers()
>       14:59:20.341 ERROR -    at SonarLint.Runner.Program.Main(String[] args)

Can anyone help me identify what key the exeception is refering to?

Comment: Is it an option to upgrade the C# plugin? There were 6 new releases since SonarLint 1.3 version.

Comment: It seems that an entry is missing from the configuration file that drives the analysis. There should be a SonarLint.xml file in your .sonarqube/conf folder. Could you check the part that belongs to this template rule (comment regular expression, S124)?

Comment: @Tamas-SonarSourceTeam See my update, did you mean that SonarLint.xml should be on the Sonar server or on the machine performing the analysis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Sonar server I'm using is shared among many teams so updating the plugin maybe be problematic.

I'm not able to find a file called SonarLint.xml, I have found reference to S124 in a file called analysis-input.xml in .sonar/ in the directory of the project I'm analyzing.

```
<Rule>
  <Key>S124</Key>
  <Parameters>
    <Parameter>
      <Key>RuleKey</Key>
      <Value>ToDo</Value>
    </Parameter>
  </Parameters>
</Rule>
```

Comment: Thanks. It seems to me that this XML misses a few additional parameters, so I'm tempted to say that there was a bug in the file generator. If you can't update the plugin, then I would say that you'll need to disable this rule in the quality profile in order to not get into the XML. (BTW, in newer versions of the C# plugin we dropped support for this template rule, and implemented separate rules for "TODO" and "FIXME" comments)

Comment: Great thanks @Tamas-SonarSourceTeam disabling that rule has fixed the crash.